# How to align image within nested div<> with spaces in div names

Tags: css, css-float

I have nested div elements with image in one of nested div on my page layout. I want to write CSS style for align image to right. How I do that:

I actually want to know how i access nested div `<div id="Imagepart1" class="new1 new1-50 adjust-right">` for writing CSS style in order to align image to right. This is how div within divs looks like:

```
<div id="Testcase1" class="item1 module">
   <div id="Div1" class="new-block">
       <div id="Imagepart1" class="new1 new1-50 adjust-right">
          <div class="new-gutter">
              <div>
                 <img alt src="/sitecollectioImages/MyWork/exampleimage.png">
              </div>
          </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on the specificity required to apply your style. You have a few options:

1. `.adjust-right { float: right; }` might be enough, this has a
   specificity of `0,0,1,0`.
2. You could also use multiple classes to target the DIV, 
   `.item1.adjust-right { float: right; }`, this has a specificity of `0,0,2,0`.
3. If not enough you can hook into the `id` attribute, `#Imagepart1 { float: right; }`, this has a specificity of `0,1,0,0`.

More on [specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) here.

It is preferred to style via options 1 and 2 and leave IDs as JS hooks.

#### Update

OP asked about using multiple CSS classes in the selector and what the difference is when leaving a space between the classes and not.

When there **IS NOT** a space between CSS classes in the CSS selector then all those classes must be present on an element for the selector to match. Without a space you are saying find class *X*, then see if class *Y* appears on the **same** element as class *X*.

If there **IS** a space between CSS classes in the CSS selector then you are targeting items that are nested. With each space you are saying (from left to right) find class *X*, then any element inside of element with class *X* find an element with class *Y*.

```html
<!-- #1 -->
<div class="outer right">        
    <!-- #2 -->
    <div class="inner left">      
         <!-- #3 -->
         <div class="core right"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Given the above markup the following selectors will:

- `.outer.right`, NO SPACE, selects the outer most DIV (#1). Requires that BOTH the `.outer` and `.right` class appear on the same element (order does not matter).
- `.outer .right`, WITH SPACE, selects the inner most DIV (#3). Requires that `.right` appear on an element somewhere inside of an element with `.outer`.

Comment: .item.adjust-right OR .item .adjust-right for accessing nested div? please clarify? when should we use space and when not between multiple classe names?

Comment: A space is used when the classes are used on different elements and those elements are nested. When there is no space between class names you are targeting the same element. I'll add a more descriptive answer in my post.

Answer (score 0):

An 'id' can be accessed with the '#' symbol and classes can be accessed via the dot operator '.' http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_syntax.asp

So you can actually target the div you described with

```
#Imagepart1{
  float: right
}
```

or accessing one of the classes attached to it

```
.adjust-right{
  float: right
}
```

or explicit use of all the classes

```
.adjust-right.new.new1-50{
   float: right;
}
```

Comment: I dont want to access div using id, because id is generated by server side control. I want to access using class name instead. I want to know if .adjust-right is enough? Can we use full class name .new1 new1-50 adjust-right?

Comment: Yes .adjust-right should be enough and honestly more preferred if you wanted to add this style to other elements as well. But if you needed to be more specific you could chain them (I updated the answer to reflect how that would look)